# Search user with empty attributes

Tags: filter, active-directory, attributes, ldap, powershell-4.0

I try to search all user with an empty attribute like `telephoneNumber` (multiple attributes query).
In the internet I found a lot about PowerShell and LDAP, but it's very complicated and nothing worked well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LDAP filters have an ugly syntax, but they're not that difficult once you understand [their structure](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx). Basically, each clause is put in a set of parentheses:

```
(attribute=value)
```

clauses can be negated:

```
(!(attribute=value))
```

and multiple clauses can be combined via logical AND or OR operations:

```
(&(attribute=somevalue)(otherattribute=othervalue)...)
(|(attribute=somevalue)(otherattribute=othervalue)...)
```

To filter for an empty attribute you need an LDAP filter saying "attribute `telephoneNumber` does not have any value":

```
(!(telephoneNumber=*))
```

The asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard for an arbitrary non-empty value. Negating that clause gives you what you want. For more complex filter you make clauses like the above (one for each attribute), and combine them with `(&...)` and/or `(|...)` according to your requirements.

Example (get users with empty `telephoneNumber` or `mail` attribute):

```psh
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(|(!(telephoneNumber=*))(!(mail=*)))'
```

---

Another option is to fetch all users and use a [`Where-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) filter for selecting those with the desired properties.

Example (again, get users with empty `telephoneNumber` or `mail` attribute):

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Where-Object {
  -not $_.telephoneNumber -or
  -not $_.mail
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was very helpful. The evaluation is done and everyone is happy. Tanks again and have a nice day.